# Is there a reference for the assembler-like output produced by `awk -W dump`?

Tags: awk, assembly, reference, mawk

The command `awk -W dump ...` produces a dump of "assembler-like" code (as shown [here [link]](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Miscellaneous-Debugger-Commands), or by reading the `man`).  Some of the instructions are easy to guess at their meaning such as `jz`, which is produced by an `if` statement and is clearly a *jump zero* instruction.  But others are less so.  Surprisingly, I can find no reference to the instruction set awk defines which seriously limits the utility of such output.

Is there any such reference online?

Comment: I think you mean gawk rather than awk.

Comment: Actually, the specific flavor I'm using, according to `which awk`, is *mawk* which is why I had also tagged the question for that variant.  Is this a relevant distinction?  Any reference would be helpful, even if it was for a different version and there were minor differences.

Comment: In gawk, look at awk.h around line 540 for the list of opcodes and profile.c to see how they are used.

Comment: It does appear that [awk.h](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gawk.git/tree/awk.h#n563) and [profile.c](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gawk.git/tree/profile.c) are relevant, but short of spending a great deal of time perusing the source, aren't immediately helpful.  If you have the ability and willingness, an answer containing at least a brief primer on how to derive an instruction's function from the source, would be most helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is mainly about `mawk`, since it uses a bytecode interpreter, and the question mentions its command-line option for showing the bytecodes in an assembly-like output.  While a [recent change to gawk](http://compgroups.net/comp.lang.awk/byte-code-version-of-3.1.8-now-available/398324) [(2010)](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.lang.awk/xf_WNB54H1A/zj3Xur8kHAgJ) added an analogous, the mnemonics (and command-line options) differ.  With gawk, you can use its debugger for getting a (different) listing.

No, there is no written *reference* aside from the source-code (which generally doesn't have comments explaining the mnemonics for the byte-code operations).

For just a *list*, you could read [`code.h`](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/mawk-snapshots/blob/master/code.h), while seeing the process of disassembling the [`da.c`](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/mawk-snapshots/blob/master/da.c) file is helpful.  However, the *action* takes place in [`execute.c`](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/mawk-snapshots/blob/master/execute.c)  But there's no tutorial.

Some recent changes have been made to make the output more understandable.  For example here's mawk 1.3.3 on the [`ct_length.awk`](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/mawk-snapshots/blob/master/examples/ct_length.awk) file:

```
MAIN
000 omain
001 jmp         084
003 pushs       "%s"
005 pushi       $0
007 pushd       1
009 pushi       i
011 pushd       5
013 add
014 pushint     3
016 substr
018 pushint     2
020 printf
022 f_pusha     $0
024 pushi       $0
026 pushi       i
028 pushd       6
030 add
031 pushint     2
033 substr
035 f_assign
036 pop
037 pushi       $0
039 pushc       0xfc2810        /^[ \t]*\(/
041 match
043 jz          078
045 pushs       "%s"
047 pushi       $0
049 pushd       1
051 pushi       RLENGTH
053 pushint     3
055 substr
057 pushint     2
059 printf
061 f_pusha     $0
063 pushi       $0
065 pushi       RLENGTH
067 pushd       1
069 add
070 pushint     2
072 substr
074 f_assign
075 pop
076 jmp         084
078 pushs       "($0)"
080 pushint     1
082 printf
084 pusha       i
086 pushi       $0
088 pushs       "length"
090 index
092 assign
093 jnz         003
095 pushint     0
097 print
099 ol_gl
```

while the 20161120 snapshot shows the finite state machine for the regular expression (near the end):

```
MAIN
000 .   omain
001 .   jmp             084
003 .   pushs   "%s"
005 .   pushi   $0
007 .   pushd   1
009 .   pushi   i
011 .   pushd   5
013 .   add
014 .   pushint 3
016 .   substr
018 .   pushint 2
020 .   printf
022 .   f_pusha $0
024 .   pushi   $0
026 .   pushi   i
028 .   pushd   6
030 .   add
031 .   pushint 2
033 .   substr
035 .   f_assign
036 .   pop
037 .   pushi   $0
039 .   pushc   0xbb7998        /^[ \t]*\(/
041 .   match
043 .   jz              078
045 .   pushs   "%s"
047 .   pushi   $0
049 .   pushd   1
051 .   pushi   RLENGTH
053 .   pushint 3
055 .   substr
057 .   pushint 2
059 .   printf
061 .   f_pusha $0
063 .   pushi   $0
065 .   pushi   RLENGTH
067 .   pushd   1
069 .   add
070 .   pushint 2
072 .   substr
074 .   f_assign
075 .   pop
076 .   jmp             084
078 .   pushs   "($0)"
080 .   pushint 1
082 .   printf
084 .   pusha   i
086 .   pushi   $0
088 .   pushs   "length"
090 .   index
092 .   assign
093 .   jnz             003
095 .   pushint 0
097 .   print
099 .   ol_gl
# regex 0xbb7998
000 .   M_START 
001 .   M_2JA   4       
002 .   M_SAVE_POS      
003 .   M_CLASS [\011 ] 
004 .   M_2JC   -2      
005 .   M_STR   "("     
006 .   M_ACCEPT
```

With gawk 4.x, you would get the analogous information by starting its debugger, e.g.,

```
gawk -D -f cf_length.awk
```

and telling it to **dump** from the command-line.  Here's the result:

```
gawk> dump

[      :0x55977de761e0] Op_newfile          : [target_jmp = 0x55977de751d0] [target_endfile = 0x55977de751f0]
                                              [target_get_record = 0x55977de75230]
[      :0x55977de75210] Op_no_op            : 
[      :0x55977de75970] Op_after_beginfile  : 
[      :0x55977de75230] Op_get_record       : [target_newfile = 0x55977de761e0]

        # Rule

[    10:0x55977de77b50] Op_rule             : [in_rule = Rule] [source_file = ct_length.awk]
[    12:0x55977de75310] Op_push_i           : 0 [MALLOC|NUMCUR|NUMBER|NUMINT]
[    12:0x55977de752f0] Op_field_spec       : 
[    12:0x55977de75370] Op_push_i           : "length" [MALLOC|STRING|STRCUR]
[    12:0x55977de752d0] Op_builtin          : index [arg_count = 2]
[    12:0x55977de75270] Op_push_lhs         : i [do_reference = false]
[    12:0x55977de75290] Op_assign           : 
[      :0x55977de75650] Op_lint             : [lint_type = LINT_assign_in_cond]
[      :0x55977de75450] Op_jmp_false        : [target_jmp = 0x55977de75810]
[    14:0x55977de75350] Op_push_i           : "%s" [MALLOC|STRING|STRCUR]
[    14:0x55977de75410] Op_push_i           : 0 [MALLOC|NUMCUR|NUMBER|NUMINT]
[    14:0x55977de753f0] Op_field_spec       : 
[    14:0x55977de75470] Op_push_i           : 1 [MALLOC|NUMCUR|NUMBER|NUMINT]
[    14:0x55977de754b0] Op_push             : i
[    14:0x55977de754d0] Op_plus_i           : 5 [MALLOC|NUMCUR|NUMBER|NUMINT]
[    14:0x55977de753d0] Op_builtin          : substr [arg_count = 3]
[    14:0x55977de752b0] Op_K_printf         : [expr_count = 2] [redir_type = ""]
[    15:0x55977de75510] Op_push_i           : 0 [MALLOC|NUMCUR|NUMBER|NUMINT]
[    15:0x55977de75530] Op_field_spec       : 
[    15:0x55977de75590] Op_push             : i
[    15:0x55977de755b0] Op_plus_i           : 6 [MALLOC|NUMCUR|NUMBER|NUMINT]
[    15:0x55977de75490] Op_builtin          : substr [arg_count = 2]
[    15:0x55977de75430] Op_push_i           : 0 [MALLOC|NUMCUR|NUMBER|NUMINT]
[    15:0x55977de753b0] Op_store_field      : 
[    17:0x55977de75570] Op_push_i           : 0 [MALLOC|NUMCUR|NUMBER|NUMINT]
[    17:0x55977de754f0] Op_field_spec       : 
[    17:0x55977de755f0] Op_push_re          : /^[ \t]*\(/
        ------[Enter] to continue or q [Enter] to quit------
[    17:0x55977de75550] Op_builtin          : match [arg_count = 2]
[      :0x55977de758b0] Op_jmp_false        : [target_jmp = 0x55977de75790]
[    20:0x55977de75630] Op_push_i           : "%s" [MALLOC|STRING|STRCUR]
[    20:0x55977de756d0] Op_push_i           : 0 [MALLOC|NUMCUR|NUMBER|NUMINT]
[    20:0x55977de756b0] Op_field_spec       : 
[    20:0x55977de75730] Op_push_i           : 1 [MALLOC|NUMCUR|NUMBER|NUMINT]
[    20:0x55977de75770] Op_push             : RLENGTH
[    20:0x55977de75690] Op_builtin          : substr [arg_count = 3]
[    20:0x55977de75610] Op_K_printf         : [expr_count = 2] [redir_type = ""]
[    21:0x55977de757d0] Op_push_i           : 0 [MALLOC|NUMCUR|NUMBER|NUMINT]
[    21:0x55977de757b0] Op_field_spec       : 
[    21:0x55977de75830] Op_push             : RLENGTH
[    21:0x55977de75850] Op_plus_i           : 1 [MALLOC|NUMCUR|NUMBER|NUMINT]
[    21:0x55977de75750] Op_builtin          : substr [arg_count = 2]
[    21:0x55977de756f0] Op_push_i           : 0 [MALLOC|NUMCUR|NUMBER|NUMINT]
[    21:0x55977de75670] Op_store_field      : 
[      :0x55977de757f0] Op_jmp              : [target_jmp = 0x55977de75870]
[    24:0x55977de75790] Op_push_i           : "($0)" [MALLOC|STRING|STRCUR]
[    24:0x55977de75710] Op_K_printf         : [expr_count = 1] [redir_type = ""]
[      :0x55977de75870] Op_no_op            : 
[      :0x55977de75390] Op_jmp              : [target_jmp = 0x55977de75310]
[      :0x55977de75810] Op_no_op            : 
[    27:0x55977de755d0] Op_K_print_rec      : [redir_type = ""]
[      :0x55977de75890] Op_no_op            : 
[      :0x55977de75950] Op_jmp              : [target_jmp = 0x55977de75230]
[      :0x55977de751f0] Op_no_op            : 
[      :0x55977de75930] Op_after_endfile    : 
[      :0x55977de751d0] Op_no_op            : 
[      :0x55977de75250] Op_atexit           : 
[      :0x55977de758d0] Op_stop             : 
gawk> q
```

If you were to put the two side-by-side, you'd see pushes and pops (since both use a similar approach to handling the stack), but little similarity beyond that.